# struggling with formatting dynamic row height in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to resize the height of my row in UITableView based on the text length. I have the following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText =[[topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:17.0];
    }
}
```

However, it messes up with the UIImageView and the UIDetailText, image shown below:

[image]

How do I fix this?

I've tried:

```
[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16,16)];
    [cell.imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16,16)];
    [cell.imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
    [cell.imageView setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```

and none seems to work

Comment: via the cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]]; I didn't show it in the code

Comment: Do you alter the imageView's contentMode?

Comment: I update my code above with the trial and errors I tried

Comment: Can you try to set it to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill?

Comment: @adit: have you considered adding your own subviews to the cell’s content view?

Comment: a custom UITableViewCell you mean?

Comment: @adit: If you want the cell to have different content components and to have these laid out in different locations, or if you want different behavioral characteristics for the cell, you have two alternatives. (a) You can add subviews to the contentView property of (b) the cell object or you can create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. See [Customizing Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subclassing as suggested by others, you could also add your own subviews to the cell’s content view.

From [Customizing Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18):

> If you want the cell to have different
>   content components and to have these
>   laid out in different locations, or if
>   you want different behavioral
>   characteristics for the cell, you have
>   two alternatives. You can add subviews
>   to the contentView property of the
>   cell object or you can create a custom
>   subclass of UITableViewCell.
>
> - You should add subviews to a cell’s content view when your content layout can be specified entirely with the   appropriate autoresizing settings and when you don’t need to modify the default behavior of the cell.
> - You should create a custom subclass when your content requires custom layout code or when you need to change the default behavior of the cell, such as in response to editing mode.

See this example:

```
#define CUSTOM_IMAGE_TAG 99
#define MAIN_LABEL 98

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UIImageView *customImageView = nil;
    UILabel *mainLabel = nil;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        customImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 40.0f)] autorelease];
        customImageView.tag = CUSTOM_IMAGE_TAG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customImageView];

        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 21.0f)] autorelease];
        mainLabel.tag = MAIN_LABEL;
        mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
    } else {
        customImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CUSTOM_IMAGE_TAG];
        mainLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAIN_LABEL];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    CGRect frame = mainLabel.frame;
    frame.size.height = ... // dynamic height
    mainLabel.frame = frame;

    return cell;
}
```

Obviously, you still need to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 2):

The work of changing cell's subviews' frames is done in `- (void)layoutSubviews` of `UITableViewCell` class, so if you want alter that behavior you can subclass common `UITableViewCell` and then do smth like:

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake( -- your own size -- );
}

@end
```

Comment: so you mean I after creating a new class that subclass the UITableViewCell I need to implement the layoutSubviews to set the size and everything?

Comment: That is correct. You'll also need to change the frame of the textLabel as it will still behave as if the large imageView was still there.

Comment: can you show me an example of the textLabel, as of now I think the UIImageView issue is fixed, but the layout of the textlabel is messy https://skitch.com/kuntul/r6fr8/ios-simulator

Answer (score 0):

I think the built in imageView will ignore your attempts to resize it. Subclass UITableViewCell and add your own custom UIImageView to it. Then you can control all aspects of your image view.

-- wisenomad's solution will work without having to add your own custom image view and labels. --

You will also have to change the frame of the textLabel. Here is an example.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        float sideLength = self.frame.size.height;
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sideLength, sideLength);
        CGRect textLabelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(44.0, textLabelFrame.origin.y, textLabelFrame.size.width - 44.0 + textLabelFrame.origin.x, textLabelFrame.size.height);
    }
```

Comment: I am getting something like this now skitch.com/kuntul/r6fr8/ios-simulator

Comment: I changed my example slightly. Try out he new code. Some of the views are over lapping which is causing your problems.