# Implementing a tableview with multiple labels inside a cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

The tableview I am implementing is a kind of phonebook, where I have an entry(name) and below that I am displaying his/her phone numbers. These data make my cell. 
An entry(name) can have multiple phone numbers(each phone number displayed in different lines). Against each phone number(in the same line) I have an option to set some status message. How can I implement this.

The way I have gone forward is:
I have created a 2 labels inside a cell. One for displaying the name and the other for displaying the numbers. These numbers are displayed in a multiline way. The problem I am facing is, adding the status message against each phone number(in the same row of each number). For that I may have to add the status as text in between the phone numbers(displayed in a multiline way) in the same label or I have to add another label inside this label. I am a bit confused regarding, how to go about this. Need help.

[image]

Comment: I would use a view for each phone number. In that view have subviews for the status and the phone number.

Comment: I'd do what @Sarah said. Just some custom cells. They are not difficult to make and they will look exactly as you want

Comment: @xavi :  see my updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnaly, I would add the "To" view as a subview of your UILabel and then set the `toView.frame.origin.y` to `index * label.font.lineHeight`.

Comment: Didn't get you completely. Could you please explain

Answer (score 3):

For multiple UILable in a cell, you can use [custom cell](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html). 
 What you are trying to implement is something like [this](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922775/struggling-with-formatting-dynamic-row-height-in-uitableview). check it out.

Comment: do you have some image or something to give some idea what you need to do?